# DeploymentItemAttribute doesn't work (correct)

Tags: c#, database, unit-testing

I have a Unit-TestClass. To test some functions for who i need database-access, i define the DeploymentItemAttribute at the head of the class directly after the TestClassAttribute.

For some reasons, running the Testclass shows very different beheaivor depending on if i run all the test of my TestProject or Testing only this units by pressing STRG+R, T.

By using CTRL+R, T, all tests of the class will succeed. By running all the tests of the testproject, they will fail because they can't find the file. By right-clicking on the Testclass in the solution-explorer and click "Run Unit-Tests", they will also fail.

I configured the file correctly. It will "always copy".
More strangely, switching the deployment-flag in the testconfigurations will also invert the results.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify it on each test method rather than just on the class? I have found that the deployment item doesn't always get picked up if you just specify it at class level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relying on my memory I can tell that by using `CTRL+R, T` you invoke default Microsoft's test runner, which deals with `DeploymentItemAttribute` as one would expect.
**But** when you say:

> By running all the tests of the testproject, they will fail because they can't find the file. By right-clicking on the Testclass in the solution-explorer and click "Run Unit-Tests", they will also fail.

I'm more then sure that these commands are provided by [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html), hence tests are run using ReSharper's test runner, which in the past [had issues with this attribute](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-273550?projectKey=RSRP&query=deploymentitem).

As for the solutions to this problem there are some mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747263/resharper-unit-test-runner-support-for-deployment-items) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130142/resharper-unit-test-runner-cant-find-content-files), but they might depend on the version of ReSharper so you might want to google it up for your specific version.